# NavMenu Items disappear when I add Bootstrap 5 links to _Host.cshtml

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side

Playing around with Blazor Server Side app in VS 2022 Community edition, started a Blazor Server app project (non-empty version) and wanted to see if I could get the Bootstrap collapsible div working . Doesn't seem to work with the default project setup so I added the current CDNs to the _Host.cshtml file. The collapsible then works but for some reason the left side nav menu goes blank. In the image below, left side is with out links, right side with links.
[image]

Hoping for some pointers on where I went wrong.

As per Mrc, the NavMenu is the generic code that VS generates for the project, I added a few more navlinks

```
    <div class="top-row ps-3 navbar navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Hub</a>


        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <nav class="flex-column">
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="home/-1/-1/-1/-1/-1" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="resorts">
                <span class="oi oi-globe" aria-hidden="true"></span> Resorts
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="contacts/-1">
                <span class="oi oi-people" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contacts
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="homeold">
                <span class="oi oi-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> Admin
            </NavLink>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string? NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Looks like it's using Bootstrap that the project includes, here is the relevant parts of the Host.cshtml :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="HUB.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

<link href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

I'm guessing that when the Bootstrap CDN links are added there is some sort of conflict or override that messes with the navmenu.

Started a new project to get rid of the syncfusion and fontawesome stuff and still the navemnu disappears when adding the CDN links. Here is the Host.cshml from the project:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace BlazorApp1test.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorApp1test.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Polite] No idea without sight of your code.  Two images is pretty unhelpful!  You need to read [mre].

Comment: Use Browser tools <F12> to look at the elements and see what CSS is being applied to the elements in question.  I'm not a Syncfusion user, so not familiar with what's in their CSS code.

Comment: Share your entire _Host.csthml code.

Comment: Small update, seemed to have solved it in a fashion. Seems the issue was the coming from the navbar toggle button:
`
        <button title="Navigation menu" class="navbar-toggler" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
`
Removed it and plus this :
`
<div class="@NavMenuCssClass nav-scrollable" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
`
And now works.